# Cookie for Django

Tags: django

I use Django 1.6 and the following error occurred:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('server ip ', 54687)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Python2.7.5/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Python2.7.5/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/Python2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Python2.7.5/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/Python2.7.5/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 124, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/local/Python2.7.5/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 92, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Python2.7.5/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 33, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I set cookie from client program. Why it happens?

It is client C# of Unity code to create cookie.

```
            Dictionary<string,string> headers = www.responseHeaders;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kvPair in headers)
            {
                if (kvPair.Key.ToLower ().Equals ("set-cookie"))
                {
                    string stHeader = "";
                    string stJoint = "";
                    string[] astCookie = kvPair.Value.Split (
                        new string[] {"; "}, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
                    foreach (string stCookie in astCookie)
                    {
                        if (!stCookie.Substring (0, 5).Equals ("path="))
                        {
                            stHeader += stJoint + stCookie;
                            stJoint = "; ";
                        }
                    }
                    if (stHeader.Length > 0)
                    {
                        this.hsHeader ["Cookie"] = stHeader;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.hsHeader.Clear ();
                    }
                }
            }
```

And I set like this

```
    WWW www = new WWW (openURL, null, this.hsHeader);
```

I think server side is okey.
Because, from browser it runs fine.

stHeader is like this

```
 csrftoken=2YiHLunt9QzqIavUbxfhp2sPVU22g3Vv; expires=Sat, 09-Apr-2016 00:11:19 GMT; Max-Age=31449600
```

Comment: Without posting the code of the view you're calling, it will be rather difficult to get any helpful answers...

Comment: @shinriyo Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059640/wsgiref-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-split

Comment: I'm sorry. I use Unity so I didn't type code. but i updated my question.