# ConnectionAborted Error: [WinError 10053] in Django Service

Tags: django, google-chrome-extension, internal-server-error

I am working on **Login,Registration** of users through **my Chrome extension**. While registration in the extension, **Django service** is stopping abruptly and **throughing some exceptions and errors**. **The error Message is as follows**:

```
C:\Users\Anusha\Desktop\DjangoServices>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 08, 2018 - 11:15:04
Django version 2.0.1, using settings 'hello.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[08/Mar/2018 11:15:44] "POST /polls/? HTTP/1.1" 200 21
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[08/Mar/2018 11:15:44] "POST /polls/? HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52297)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 86, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 154, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
[08/Mar/2018 11:26:19] "GET /polls HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[08/Mar/2018 11:26:19] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/Mar/2018 11:26:20] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2079
```

These errors are occurring during login and registration. Suggest me how to resolve these errors and exceptions.

Comment: It dies on a POST request and seems to work for GET. You may want to add further details (like if the login/registration succeeds via a regular webpage or not, if it should be a POST at all or not, perhaps completed with some code snippets).

Comment: **ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine**
Server or your local machine's installed software like antivirus aborted request.

Comment: Please suggest me another resources

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wsgiref Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059640/wsgiref-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-split)

Comment: I have referred the above link but i couldn't resolve the issues. Suggest me what changes i have to do

Comment: I have checked in a fix for this in Python: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9713 It will be available in the next version of Python 3.7 and later.